# How to create a logo made of fire?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects

I need to make a version of a logo "made of fire" for an ad. Take a look at the images below. The last one is a test I made using Apple's logo using [this set](http://narvils.deviantart.com/art/Fire-stock-pt-2-of-3-217825809) of transparent flames. As you can see, IT'S WEIRD.

I know, what I'm trying to accomplish it's not easy. But I consider to have advanced photoshop skills. Still, everything i tried it just stays super weird! Do you think it's **possible** to make this images only with photoshop? How would you do it? With brushes, maybe?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using liquify and puppet warp? The first one look like masked flame (for the body) and then some brush work with glow. The Phoenix is a set of many flames photos and done with filters like in this tutorial http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-flaming-photo-manipulation--psd-1779

Comment: also I believe it looks weird because the logo is one big solid geometric shape. The others are more organic and the fire sort of follows the shapes.

Answer (score 1):

if you're not bound by Photoshop and know a thing or two about Illustrator maybe you can try creating your own flames in it. **Here** under [this link](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-burning-vector-match-using-gradient-meshes--vector-4349)
 you'll find a tutorial for creating a vector-based 3d burning match. You can skip to the part where author focuses on creation of flames.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this entirely in Photoshop, but having a graphics tablet capable of reading stylus tilt and rotation will make this easier. Otherwise, there is plenty of flame stock art you can manipulate and composite.

One way to go about this is to prepare a "fire" gradient going from transparent black, to thin red, on through to orange and yellow, then thinning out again. You can also add white and faint colors such as green or blue (with chemistry determining what color to use). Apply this to a Gradient Fill layer (Layer > New Fill Layer > Gradient) and set it to a mode like Linear Dodge. Pick out a suitable brush, likely a natural media flat brush with reduced flow. Your strokes should resemble ripples on thin, crumpled fabric. Larger strokes should have an upward or wind-following motion.

You may also find pre-made fire brushes useful. To build up the effect, you can use multiple layers, each with a different arrangement of strokes. You may get better results by keeping the size of the flame licks consistent, and varying their scale to suit your basis.